# Is there a tool/hack that enables dragging windows from one monitor to the other in Mission Control?

Tags: macos, display, mission-control

Right now I have dual monitor set-up as shown below.
[image]

When I activate Mission Control it looks like this:
[image]

Now I want to drag the Finder windows to the other monitor as indicated by the arrow.
However, the window just jumps back to the original monitor.

I know ways of moving windows to other monitors outside of Mission Control, but doing this in Mission Control allows for moving groups of windows to different monitors. 
Also I would like to keep the task of window arrangement in Mission Control.

I'm on the latest Mountain Lion. Is there some sort of hack, plugin or tool that will allow me to do this move in Mission Control?

Comment: Do you really want to know that "no - this isn't possible" or perhaps you could relax the criteria that it has to be within Mission Control and just stipulate you want that functionality to move a group of windows. I could see options like Divvy and other that might do everything you wish except hack Mission Control.

Comment: Sometimes there are pref file hacks or additions that make these sort of things possible. Dropping the Mission Control restriction does make it simpler, but I'm already aware of (some of) these solutions. If you feel this question is not constructive or only of use for a very small amount of people feel free to close it.

Comment: Just nudging you to see if Mission Control was mandatory. :) it's certainly fine as is, just more likely to languish but in the end sounds like it's phrased perfectly for your intent